# Showing continuity using Weierstrass M test

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}x^4$$ defines a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$.

My proof: For any $M>0$ and $x\in [-M,M]$, $$|\sum\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}x^4| \le \sum \frac{M^4}{n^2}<\infty$$ So by Weierstrass M-test, it uniformly converges to a function $f(x)$ in $[-M,M]$. Since each term of series is continuous, the uniform limit $f$ should be continuous. **Since this holds for any $M>0$, the series defines a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$.**

Actually, I'm not quite sure about the boldfaced line. Is it okay? Also is my proof natural and good, or is there a better proof?

Comment: Looks good to me. If you're worried about going from $[-M,M]$ to the entire line you could start the proof with something like "Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ and let $M > |x_0|$". Once you've proved $f$ is continuous on $[-M,M]$ you conclude it is continuous at $x_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof shows that $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval $[-M,M]$ for any $M$. You can use this fact to show that $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$, but you are right that the bolded line does not provide justification (it just assumes you can fill in the details). The proof is otherwise natural and good.

Here's how I would prove the bolded statement. Recall that continuity is a local property, so it suffices to show that $f$ is continuous at $p$ for all $p\in \mathbb R$. Fix some $p$, and choose $M$ large enough so that $p\in [-M, M]$. Then $f$ is continuous at all points in $[-M,M]$, so in particular it is continuous at $p$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, this shows it is continuous at all points in $\mathbb R$.